# Full node deposit balance not working

Tags: nodes

I'm running ethereum node with this command

> geth --fast --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain * --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3

And I've created an ethereum address, but and when I deposit some money to this ethereum address from external wallet, money did not arrrive into the new wallet address.

What could be missing?

Blockchain is fully downloaded with above command and syncing is upto date.

Comment: Can you specify how you actually send the "money" to your newly created address ?

Comment: money was sent from other website ethereum wallet. it was just $10 for testing before 12 hours but it did not arrived

Comment: it arrived when i sent again